Project Feasibility and Advice on Microcontrollers
I'd like to make a supercluster of small microcontrollers to do "big" tasks. My plan is to have them be a sort of processor for a raspberry pi zero, which divides the tasks among them. For example, computational work would be done by the MCUs, after being tasked by the raspberry pi. Is this feasible?
If so, I would like to use MCUs that are relatively inexpensive so that I can have many things going on at once. What MCU would be best for this? I was thinking something with a lot of proccessing power for its price, like an ATTiny brand MCU or even a CH32V003.
Thanks!

Whether or not a cluster can perform better than a centralized processor depends completely on the task to be performed. There is no quicker communication that the register to register communication in a CPU. Distributed computing, with its higher communication costs may (not necessarily) be slower than a single CPU. It all depends.

This is far too broad as it stands. Do you have any particular "big task" in mind? Can you characterize it in terms of its data input and output requirements, and the expected number of operations it takes to complete the task? Can the task be broken down into sub-tasks that can run in parallel? If so, how much communication among the sub-tasks is required? These are the kinds of questions you need to consider before you get anywhere close to picking an actual MCU.

For many tasks, you'll find that the host-to-cluser and MCU-to-MCU communications requirements become a huge bottleneck in terms of getting meaningful throughput. But as a real-world example, many years ago (mid-1980s, IIRC), Steve Ciarcia (of "Circuit Cellar" fame) put together a cluster of 8051 MCUs to compute Mandlebrot sets. This is a task that requires no MCU-to-MCU communication at all, and very little host-to-MCU communication relative to the amount of computing required. But very few useful tasks have this property.

@DaveTweed The task I have in mind is to evaluate hashes, I know arduinos and other MCUs can do that, so I figured I could make a cluster of them. It can therefore be broken down into tasks that can run in parallel. Communication would happen between the nodes and raspberry pi through a bus, which I plan to integrate. Thank you for your response.
That is a good example for communication, and I hadn't fully thought that part out yet. I am open to suggestions of ways to make this project come to light!

@AmateurE Much work has gone into using thousands of processors to perform tasks. Apollo's DN3000 system could connect up hundreds or thousands of workstations and run a single application on just one of them. It would "anneal" out, trading network bandwidth and RPC call costs against running code granules. You could literally watch, in real-time, as the application spread itself throughout the network to run as fast as possible. It wasn't static, always trading one thing for another in a markoff chain monte carlo simulated annealing process. Later, the transputer was presented as an idea too.

@AmateurE We are talking 1980's and early 1990's here. Ancient history. Modern approaches include directions that Microsoft is pursuing today in bundles of workloads connected through thousands of parallel pipes. Someone I've known all my life has also been working in this area, since getting his PhD. You could view current status here. His work is on ScalPL (Scalable Planning Language), Software Cabling, Coooperative Data Sharing -- open sourced as CDS-BCR) and PICA. He wrote, "Scalable Planning: Concurrent Action from Elemental Thinking" in 2012.

@AmateurE However, I suspect for your needs you don't need anywhere near such a deep-dive. Describe the application space a little more and where you are headed with it. Perhaps the final destination warrants all the early work you suggest. But perhaps not.

You just want to demonstrate this then find a processor that has a lot of m0-m3 cores in it

If this is for learning about offloading tasks and communication, perhaps something based upon the Xilinx Zync family, e.g. Z-turn Board or MYD-CZU3EG/4EV/5EV-V2 Development Board. They have one chip with ARM cores plus FPGA fabric.
That could allow the creation of "offload" engines in the FPGA fabric which communicate with software running on the ARM cores. The Xilinx tools allows the ARM cores to Linux or bare-metal applications.
The communication on-chip avoids having to wire buses between boards.

@AmateurEnthusiast Calculate hashes in parallel? OK, what hashes specifically? Modern CPUs have accelerators for that and even GPUs can do a lot of them in parallel. A simple 8-bit RISC machine such as the ATTiny AVR needs to perform each step of the algorithm and do it 8 bits at a time at slow speeds like 20 MHz. Your CPUs and GPUs run at least 10x if not 100x at that speed and can use 32 or 64 bit operations insteaf of 8.

ESP32s with WiFi MAY give you good performance/$ and the built in WiFi MAY assist the communications task in some cases.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilera

A single Raspberry Pi which has multiple 32/64 bit ARM cores has likely more processing power than what you get from a bunch of 8-bit AVR MCUs for the same price.
The ATTinys may seem to have a lot of processing power for their price, so they are just really cheap, they do not necessarily have a lot of processing power.
The next problem is, all the AVRs would need to be flashed with a program that is suited for that specific computational task. They cannot be uploaded with a new program to RAM for execution. They are only rated for 10000 flashing cycles.
They are quite limited in RAM too.
Also you would need to communicate with a cluster of MCUs somehow. If you add say a RS-485 interface for each MCU, it likely doubles the price. And a crystal to have precise enough clock for UART. And regulators, bypass caps and a power supply.
So it can be done, you decide if it is feasible or not.
You can try it first by simulating a few hundred ATTinys with the Raspberry Pi, in which case each simulated AVRs likely run at 10x to 100x speeds faster than the real AVR chip.

That's all good information, although it is quite unfortunate for my project. Out of curiosity, how would I go about simulating the ATTinys with the Raspberry Pi?

@AmateurEnthusiast The linux repos likely have multiple you can install with apt-get.
